# how to get the data type of a property in a db.Model in appengine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm storing data dynamically in the data store, so i have to know the type of a property, before storing the value. I already read the documentation for the class model and i didn't find the answer. 
I'll apreciate all the help

suppose i have two types of entities.

```
    class Custom_Suppl(db.Model):
        code=db.StringProperty(required=True)

    class Inventory(db.Model):
        code=db.FloatProperty(required=True)
```

I have a function that stores values in those entities

```
    def storeValues(databaseName,values)
        ....some code...
```

you see that the two entities, have the same property name, but different types of value.. So i must convert the value to the corresponding type. How do i get the type of the property? I hope this clarifies it.

Comment: What are you asking for? Are you not defining the types yourself?

Comment: Are you storing data in a particular property based on your input? Usually you specify exactly which fields in the datastore are to be updated in a given model, and you would check the type of the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that there's a class method .properties() in the class model. It returns a dictionary of all the properties in a especific  entity. Each property is a property class. [See Here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass#Property_data_type). It has an class attribute data_type.